# jquery .load() after page call function

Tags: jquery

I am using function to jQuery `.load()`.
I want to execute `function(testFnc)` of after page.
This function is onclick event.

And I want using variable of b.aspx.

This is the code:

```
//a.aspx page code
$('#divArea').load('b.aspx');

//b.aaspx page code
function testFnc() {
 //code
}
...
```

edit code :

```
//a.aspx page code
$('#divArea').load('b.aspx');

//b.aaspx page code
function testFnc(param) {
//code
}
...
<span onclick='testFnc(params);'>button</span>
```

Comment: The documentation of [jQuery load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is a useful place for such kind of questions. `[...]If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.[...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the callback for on `load()` method. Callback function executed when load `load()` execution completes.

```
<span id="loadb">button</span>

$("#loadb").on('click', function(){
    $('#mydiv').load('b.aspx', function() {
        // This gets executed when the content is loaded
        testFnc()
    });

    function testFnc() {
        //code
    }
});
```

Comment: I fixed the question. Please check a question.
I want to span tag onclick event of b.aspx page.
Is this possible?

Comment: @JisubKim Ok I will update answer.

Comment: @JisubKim what is inside the param?

Comment: @JisubKim you want to load `b.aspx` on button click?

Comment: yes. i want to b.aspx on button click.
And string is inside the param.

Comment: Hi @JisubKim I have updated my answer, can you say what could be the exact value of `param`, I mean from where do you get that value.

Comment: Sorry. button is inside the b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `load()` has two parameters `url` and `callback` function. when `load()` execute complete `callback` function get fired.

```
$( "#divArea" ).load( "b.aspx", function() {
  testFnc();
});
```

Comment: @JisubKim try this answer